# Jquery & PHP not directing to header function

Tags: php, jquery

I have this simple login form with Jquery, ajax & PHP when the login is successful the home page is showing in div section instead of going to a next webpage. Any suggestions?

HTML Form:

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(){
            var userid = $('#userid').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
            if (userid == '' || password == '') {
                $("#msg").html("All Fields Required");
                return false;
            }
            $.ajax({
                data: {"userid":userid, "password":password},
                type: $(this).attr('method'),
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                success: function(data){
                    $("#msg").html(data);
                }});
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="login.php">
    <input id="userid" name="userid" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID">
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><b>Login</b></button>
    <h4 align="center" id="msg" style="background-color: red; color: white;"></h4>
</form>
```

PHP code:

```php
<?php
include 'db.php';

$user = $_POST['userid'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM login WHERE userid='$user' AND password='$pass'") or die (mysqli_error($con));
$result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
  $_SESSION['user'] = $row['userid'];
}

if(!$result){
  echo "Username or Password is incorrect!";
}else{
  header("Location: claims.php?id='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You can not redirect the _front end_, by responding to a _background request_ with a redirect. That response “lands” in your JavaScript code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: can you tell me the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer is to redirect with Javascript

```
echo '<script>window.location.href = "claims.php?id='.$_SESSION['id'].'";</script>';
```